# Magento2: what is the basic difference between plugin and preference?

Tags: magento2, plugin, magento2-dev-beta, preference

I used both **Plugin** and **Preference** in **Magento2** tutorial and both are working fine but what is the basic difference between them.

Code for plugin:

1.1) Add a plugin declaration into di.xml:

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
<plugin name="magento-catalog-product-plugin" type="Training\Test\Model\Product" sortOrder="10"/>
</type>
```

1.2) Create a plugin class:

```
<?php
namespace Training\Test\Model;
class Product {
public function afterGetPrice(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product, $result) {
return 5;
}
}
```

Code for preference:

2.1) Create a preference declaration:

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product"
type="Training\Test\Model\Testproduct" />
```

2.2) Create a new Product class:

```
<?php
namespace Training\Test\Model;
class Testproduct extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
{
public function getPrice() {
return 3;
}
}
```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

A preference is equivalent to class rewriting from Magento 1. It's equivalent to saying, "Whenever code asks for `ClassA`, give them `MyClassB` instead." `MyClassB` is expected to be a complete implementation of `ClassA`, plus whatever behavior you add or modify on top.

As in Magento 1, only one preference (rewrite) can be active for a class at one time unless you chain them manually (such that `MyClassB` extends `OtherClassB`, and `OtherClassB` extends `ClassA`).

A plugin allows you to execute code before, around, or after methods from the class you're hooking onto. Your plugin class does not replace the target class, and it is not an instance of it. You just have methods `before{method}`, `around{method}`, `after{method}` which get executed at the appropriate time in respect to {method} on the target class.

Since plugins do not replace the target class, any number of plugins can be active on a class simultaneously. Magento just executes them one after another based on the sortOrder parameter in your XML.

Because of that, plugins are much more flexible than preferences. You should use plugins whenever possible, and avoid preferences for rewriting classes unless absolutely necessary.

You can read more about how plugins work and how to use them in the [official documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html).

Comment: Preference is not equivalent to class rewriting. It is way to provide default implementation for interfaces.

Comment: @KAndy That may be the basic intended purpose, but a side effect of that is they also work for class overriding. Semantically they are the same. Class rewriting via preferences is what Yogesh was asking about, and also what the Fundamentals exercise he was working on instructs you to do.

Answer (score 23):

**In simple words**

> Preference is used for overriding class
>
> Plugin is used for adding functionality before, after and around
>   methods.

**For As Your example:**

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" type="Vendor\MyModule\Block\Product\ListProduct" />
```

Whenever code ask for ListProduct, **preference said that**

**Hey,  use** `Vendor\MyModule\Block\Product\ListProduct` **instead of** `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct`

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
<plugin name="magento-catalog-product-plugin" type="Training\Test\Model\Product" sortOrder="10"/>
</type>
```

Whenever code ask for getPrice(), **plugin said that**

**Hey use my** `getPrice()` **method before, after and around your** `getPrice()` **method**

Comment: Good Explanation +1 for that

Comment: Nice one!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

In brief :

> Preference is used to specify the default implementation of an interface.
>
> Plugin ( Interceptor ) is used to extend the behavior of a public method of another class.

In detail :

**Preference :**
If there is more than one class that implements an interface, then it is important to specify the default one of all the implemented classes. This is done through the preference node in the dependency injection file ( di.xml ).

Example :

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" type="Vendor\MyModule\Block\Product\ListProduct" />
```

This mapping is in `app/etc/di.xml`, so the object manager injects the `Magento\Core\Model\Url` implementation class wherever there is a request for the `Magento\Core\Model\UrlInterface` in the global scope.

**Plugin(Interceptor) :**

Say, a class `A` has method `methodA` which needs an extended functionality. Then, this is achieved through Plugins by creating class `APlugin` without modifying the original class `A`. Class `APlugin` has methods that runs before, after or around the required method.

Example :

```
<config>
    <type name="Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Config\Backend\ShowOutOfStock">
        <plugin name="showOutOfStockValueChanged" type="Magento\Catalog\Model\Plugin\ShowOutOfStockConfig"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

This mapping is in app/etc/di.xml. One/Few of the class `Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Config\Backend\ShowOutOfStock` method(s) are executed before/after/around the class `Magento\Catalog\Model\Plugin\ShowOutOfStockConfig` methods.