# Change Category thumbnail with swatch which is not from gallery

Tags: category, magento-2.1, color-swatches

I have hidden my thumbnail from the gallery as what I display in the category listing is not the same image as what I want to show in the gallery (it has extra bits in it).

In the JsonConfig object, I got from the swatch, I have the list of the images from the Gallery but not my thumbnail.

How can I modify the JsonConfig object to add an item to it?

Do I extend the question to "how to add another image role in the JsonConfig object? (i.e. not only the thumbnail)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea was here to extend the class `\Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Listing\Configurable` and particularly the method `_getAdditionalConfig()`. Below is my code, the 2 images roles I wanted to extract are called `category_mobile` and `category_tablet`.

**app/code/Memes/Extendjsonconfig/registration.php**

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
'Memes_Extendjsonconfig',
__DIR__
);
```

**app/code/Memes/Extendjsonconfig/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Listing\Configurable" type="Memes\Extendjsonconfig\Block\Product\Renderer\Listing\Configurable" />
</config>
```

**app/code/Memes/Extendjsonconfig/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Memes_Extendjsonconfig" setup_version="0.0.1"/>
</config>
```

**app/code/Memes/Extendjsonconfig/Block/Product/Renderer/Listing/configurable.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by memes (http://chezmemes.com)
 * Date: 26/10/2016
 * Time: 6:02 PM
 */
namespace Memes\Extendjsonconfig\Block\Product\Renderer\Listing;


class Configurable extends \Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Listing\Configurable
{


protected function _getAdditionalConfig()
{
    $image_mobile = 'category_mobile';
    $image_tablet = 'category_tablet';

    return [$image_mobile => $this->getOptionImages($image_mobile), $image_tablet => $this->getOptionImages($image_tablet) ];
}

protected function getOptionImages($imageRole)
{
    $images = [];
    foreach ($this->getAllowProducts() as $product) {

        $mobileImage = $product->getData($imageRole);   
                if(isset($mobileImage) && $mobileImage != 'no_selection' ){
                    $mobileImageAttr = $product->getCustomAttribute( $imageRole );
                    $image = $mobileImageAttr->getValue();
                }
                else{
                    $image="";
                } 
        $images[$product->getId()] =
            [
                'path' => $image
            ];
    }
    return $images;
}
}
```

This gives me the relative path of the images in the folder `http://www.store.com/pub/media/catalog/product`, I can then use it in my Javascript to update whatever I want.

This would be easily extendable to any other attribute needed.

A variant would be to use a Plugin rather than a preference, this is discussed in [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/109236/magento2-how-to-use-getadditionalconfig-from-magento-configurableproduct-b/142732#142732)

Comment: thank you for this answer. i was about to post the question for this function.