# Overriding Block file is not working in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, blocks, overrides, sales-order, preference

Today I am trying to overwrite the `\Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View` file, but it's not working. The same coding working on core files.

**My Code is**

```
<?php

namespace SR\StackExchange\Block\Adminhtml\Order;

class View extends \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View
{

    /**
     * Get URL for back (reset) button
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCustomOrderUrl()
    {
        $params = [
            'id' => $this->getOrderId(),
            'store' => 0
        ];

        return $this->getUrl('stackexchange/stackexchange/order');
    }

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @return void
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {

        $this->buttonList->add(
            'custom_button',
            [
                'label' => __('Custom Button'),
                'class' => 'action-secondary',
                'on_click' => sprintf("location.href = '%s';", $this->getCustomOrderUrl()),
            ]
        );

        parent::_construct();
    }

}
```

**etc/adminhtml/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">   
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View">
        <plugin name="custom_button" type="SR\StackExchange\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you misunderstanding **plugins and preferences**.

If you want to override an entire class you need to use preferences:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">   
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View"
                type="SR\StackExchange\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View" />
</config>
```

You can get a good read about the differences between plugins and preferences here: [Magento2: what is the basic difference between plugin and preference?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/85277/magento2-what-is-the-basic-difference-between-plugin-and-preference)