# Override magento2 module sales files in custom module

Tags: magento2, overrides, sales

How to override the following files in our custom module

```
/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml
```

and

```
/vendor/magento/module-sales/Block/Adminhtml/Order/View/Items/Renderer/DefaultRenderer.php
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

In order to override a layout file, you just need to create a new layout file with the same name i.e. layout handle in your custom module.

Like in your case, you need to create a layout file with the name sales_order_view.xml and place that into the same same adminhtml/layout dir in your module.

> app/code/{NameSpace}/{Module}/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml

Moving further, you can override a php file by different ways in M2. Like if you want to tweak request/response of a public method then you can use Plugin.

You can also observe an event if there is any being dispatched from the class that you wish to override.

And last, you can also use Preference to override a class. Here are some references.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/events-and-observers.html
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/85291/23943

Answer (score 0):

Inside `Module.xml` file, you have to declare dependency of core module

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Modulename" setup_version="1.0.0" active="true">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

You have to override your xml file at right place,

> app/code/Vendor/Modulename/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

     <preference for="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Items\Renderer\DefaultRenderer" type="Vendor\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Items\Renderer\DefaultRenderer" /> 
</config>
```

Create DefaultRenderer.php in

> Vendor\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Items\Renderer.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Items\Renderer;

class DefaultRenderer extends \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Items\Renderer\DefaultRenderer
{

}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but how can I add code in sale_order_view.xml

Answer (score 0):

```
Create custom module for same and you can override like this

Create sales_order_view.xml file in your custom module
Vendor/Mymodule/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml


For example if you want to override items.phtml file then you can override like this

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="order_items">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Mymodule::order/view/items.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

> app/code/vendorname/modulename/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Items\Renderer" type="vendorname\modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Items\Renderer" />
</config>
```

> app/code/vendorname/modulename/Block/Adminhtml/Order/View/Items/Renderer/DefaultRenderer.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Items\Renderer;

class DefaultRenderer extends \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Items\Renderer\DefaultRenderer
{

}
```

> app/code/vendorname/modulename/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="order_items">
            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Items" name="order_items" template="Magento_Sales::order/view/items.phtml">
                <arguments>
                        <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">

                                <item name="seller_demo" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Seller</item>

                        </argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Hi @Zala thanks for the ewply but how can I add code in sale_order_view.xml

Comment: which code add sale_order_view.xml.

Comment: above code are Override DefaultRenderer.php file.

Comment: ok but i need to add code in sale xml also

Comment: which code add sale_order_view.xml.

Comment: This line should be added https://prnt.sc/hbjq55
to show https://prnt.sc/hbjqaw

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68860/discussion-between-ravindrasinh-zala-and-raghu).

Comment: <item name="seller_demo" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Seller</item>