# Magento 2: How to override model resource configurable file

Tags: magento2, resource-model

I have created a custom module.

**di.xml**

> < type
>   name="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable">
>            < plugin name="ptgConfigurableProduct" type="ModuleName\Extendfiles\Plugin\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable"
>   sortOrder="1" />    < /type>

**Path:** /ModuleName/Extendfiles/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Type/
**Configurable.php**

> namespace
>   ModuleName\Extendfiles\Plugin\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type;
>
> class Configurable extends
>   \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable
>   {
>
> }

**Function**

> public function afterGetAttributeOptions($superAttribute, $productId){
>
> ```
>     $scope  = $this->getScopeResolver()->getScope();
>     $select = $this->getConnection()->select()->from(
>         ['super_attribute' => $this->getTable('catalog_product_super_attribute')],
>         [
>             'sku' => 'entity.sku',
>             'product_id' => 'product_entity.entity_id',
>             'attribute_code' => 'attribute.attribute_code',
>             'value_index' => 'entity_value.value',
>             'option_title' => $this->getConnection()->getIfNullSql(
>                 'option_value.value',
>                 'default_option_value.value'
>             ),
>             'default_title' => 'default_option_value.value',
>         ]
>     )->joinInner(
>         ['product_entity' => $this->getTable('catalog_product_entity')],
>         "product_entity.{$this->getProductEntityLinkField()} = super_attribute.product_id",
>         []
>     )->joinInner(
>         ['product_link' => $this->getTable('catalog_product_super_link')],
>         'product_link.parent_id = super_attribute.product_id',
>         []
>     )->joinInner(
>         ['attribute' => $this->getTable('eav_attribute')],
>         'attribute.attribute_id = super_attribute.attribute_id',
>         []
>     )->joinInner(
>         ['entity' => $this->getTable('catalog_product_entity')],
>         'entity.entity_id = product_link.product_id',
>         []
>     )->joinInner(
>         ['entity_value' => 'catalog_product_entity_int'],
>         implode(
>             ' AND ',
>             [
>                 'entity_value.attribute_id = super_attribute.attribute_id',
>                 'entity_value.store_id = 0',
>                 "entity_value.{$this->getProductEntityLinkField()} = "
>                 . "entity.entity_id",
>             ]
>         ),
>         []
>     )->joinLeft(
>         ['option_value' => $this->getTable('eav_attribute_option_value')],
>         implode(
>             ' AND ',
>             [
>                 'option_value.option_id = entity_value.value',
>                 'option_value.store_id = ' . $scope->getId(),
>             ]
>         ),
>         []
>     )->joinLeft(
>         ['default_option_value' => $this->getTable('eav_attribute_option_value')],
>         implode(
>             ' AND ',
>             [
>                 'default_option_value.option_id = entity_value.value',
>                 'default_option_value.store_id = ' . \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,
>             ]
>         ),
>         []
>     )->where(
>         'super_attribute.product_id = ?',
>         $productId
>     )->where(
>         'option_value.value != "N/A"',
>         $productId
>     )->where(
>         'attribute.attribute_id = ?',
>         $superAttribute->getAttributeId()             $attributeId
>     );
>
>   return $this->getConnection()->fetchAll($select);
>   }
> ```

Getting below error for this code

> $superAttribute->getAttributeId()

,
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable\Interceptor::getAttributeId()

Comment: Are you working on developer mode?

Comment: yes, it's already in developer mode, and i have already try with commands

Comment: Have you added 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1); this code to index.php ?

Comment: Still public function not working and also not showing any error

Comment: Did you got solution?

Comment: yes, Now  public function afterGetAttributeOptions($superAttribute, $productId){} it's call but but getting this error: Fatal error: Call to undefined method Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable\Interceptor::getAttributeId() 

,,,, There is some issue with $superAttribute->getAttributeId()       ,,,,,,,,,     I have add other private and public function but still not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81376/discussion-between-suresh-chikani-and-jimit).

Answer (score 0):

As per as your code, you have to try to use [Plugin](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html) as you have using `afterGetAttributeOptions` which **after plugin method** on `getAttributeOptions`.

But, at `di.xml` you have tried override `Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable`

In magento2 Plugin & Preference two different things. See [Magento2: what is the basic difference between plugin and preference?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/85277/magento2-what-is-the-basic-difference-between-plugin-and-preference)

At the single word,  PLugin can change only the public functions behavior of a class. Where  **Preference** Can change the behavior of any functions of class.

So, to your case, if want to change out the behavior of `getAttributeOptions` method then you can use after/around/before the plugin method.

Then that case you have to define your class at plugin by below code at your di.xml.

```
<config>
...
    <type name="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable">
      <plugin name="{pluginName}" type="Module\Namespace\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
..
</config>
```

***If you rewrite the class using `Preference` the class then 
 That case, you cannot use afterGetAttributeOptions,beforeGetAttributeOptions,aroundGetAttributeOptions as, those method are plugin method.***

### Update

**UNDERSTAND form chat**

from the  chat, you have to  use plugin  on `Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Attribute\OptionSelectBuilder` and create   create after plugin  over `getSelect`

**di.xml**

```
 <type name="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Attribute\OptionSelectBuilder">
          <plugin name="{pluginName}" type="Module\Namespace\Plugin\ResourceModel\Attribute\OptionSelectBuilder" sortOrder="1" />
</type>
```

***Plugin Class**

```
<?php
namespace Module\Namespace\Plugin\ResourceModel\Attribute;
class OptionSelectBuilder
{
    public function afterGetSelect(
    \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Attribute\OptionSelectBuilder $subject,
     $result
    ){
    {
        return $result->where( 
            'option_value.value != "N/A"', 
                $productId 
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: now getting this error: Fatal error: Call to undefined method Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable\Interceptor::getAttributeId() in /Modulename/Extendfiles/Plugin/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Type/Configurable.php on line

Comment: There is some issue at here: $superAttribute->getAttributeId()

Comment: what you want to use plugin or preference?

Comment: i have update di.xml file now i have use plugin

Comment: i have add function which i want to override and getting error near $superAttribute->getAttributeId() this code at bottom

Comment: Sorry,i  don't understand what you want to achieve.The code under `afterGetAttributeOptions` function i donot see that `Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable`

Comment: Pretty connfuse me...

Comment: afterGetAttributeOptions($superAttribute, $productId)  is  wrong it should be  `public function afterGetAttributeOptions(
 \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable $subject,
  \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\AbstractAttribute $superAttribute,
  $productId
 `

Comment: pdp page now showing 404 page not found, and at home page getting this error:  1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Strict Notice: Declaration of Modulename\Namespace\Plugin\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable\Interceptor::afterGetAttributeOptions() should be compatible with Modulename\Namespace\Plugin\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable::afterGetAttributeOptions(Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable $superAttribute, Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\AbstractAttribute $superAttribute, $productId)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81390/discussion-between-jimit-and-amit-bera).

Comment: I have update my code, when i pass arguments as you suggest, getting above error