# What are the best way to customize Magento 2 core

Tags: magento2, module, php-7

How I can customize **Magento 2**  core module?

Can I create **new module** or override core modules?

Answer (score 1):

If want to change in any `template`,`js`,`xml` and `html` file then you will be need to override in your theme using path :

> app/design/frontend/{{vendor}}/{{theme}}/Vendor_Module/

If you want to change `block`,`model`,`cotroller` and `helper` then you will be need to create your module and rewrite your logic on this module using `di.xml`

Comment: Thanks 
What is module and what is plug in

Comment: @prabhakaran7 You want to applying code and some logic before, after, or around a public method, a plugin extends or modifies that method’s behavior

Comment: thank you 
if i want to edit the search functionality and checkout module 

can i copy the vendor/magento_module/*(which module)

to app/code/Changing_core/


like this and edit the code

Comment: if want to change in any template,js,xml and html and create your theme and override template file in your them. for example: app/design/frontend/{{vendor}}/{{theme}}/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart.phtml.  Block and other php file and you want to create new module and rewrite Block file using di.xml

Comment: ok thank you ... can i get your email  contact for future use

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89071/discussion-between-saneer-ladani-and-prabhakaran7).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, basically you can override **Magento core modules** by creating your own **custom module.**
Here's an example on how to create your own module:

> Step 1: Create a module folder for Magento 2 Modules
>
> Module name is **HelloMagento** and Vendor name is **CustomVendor**
>   create a new folder:         **app/code/CustomVendor/HelloMagento**
>
> Step 2: Declare the module by module.xml
>   Create a configuration in module etc directory.
>   Magento 2 will use it to recognize the **module’s name and module’s version**
>
> **app/code/CustomVendor/HelloMagento/etc/module.xml**
>   Add this content to declare module name HelloMagento and version 1.0.0

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="CustomVendor_HelloMagento" setup_version="1.0.0" />
</config>
```

> Step 3: Register the module by registration.php
>   This file will be created in magento root folder:
>   **app/code/CustomVendor/HelloMagento/registration.php**
>   Add this content to register the module:

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'CustomVendor_HelloMagento',
    __DIR__
);
```

> Step 4: Install Setup, Enable the module
>   After create all files of above steps.
>   You can install the module through command line.
>   Open your terminal and use these commands:

```
cd [magento_directory]
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

> Step 5: Create a route for the module
>   url Format: http://.com///
>   Example: `http://<magento_url>/customer/account/create`
>
> Create a routers.xml file:
>   **app/code/CustomVendor/HelloMagento/etc/frontend/routes.xml**
>   Add this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="yourstore" frontName="hellomagento">
            <module name="CustomVendor_HelloMagento" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

> Step 6: Create controller and action
>   In the last step, we will create url for displaying in your browser:
>    **“Hello Magento 2!. We will change the world!”.**
>
> Create an action file:
>   **app/code/CustomVendor/HelloMagento/Controller/Index/Index.php**
>   Add the content:

```
<?php
namespace CustomVendor\HelloMagento\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
  public function __construct(
\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context)
  {
    return parent::__construct($context);
  }

  public function execute()
  {
    echo 'Hello Magento 2! We will change the world!';
    exit;
  }
}
```

> Result: 
>   Open your browser, enter this link: `http://<magento_url>/hellomagento/index/index` and look at the result:
>   **`Hello Magento 2! We will change the world!`**
>
> With your **Magento 2 custom Module** you will be able to override Magento core modules using **Plugins** and **Observers**

Reference for creating and using Plugins to override Magento Core function:
[Magento2 – Create and Use Plugins](https://webkul.com/blog/magento2-use-plugins/)

Reference for creating Module: [Magento 2 Module](https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/magento-2-modules/)

Answer (score 0):

Both way you can do it.

It depends on your requirement. What actually you want.

If there are some modification then you can done in core magento.

If there are some major changes like customisation in predefined module then you can override custom module.

If modification are there you can use **Plugins** and if you want to handle the event then you can go with **Observer**.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you how i can override core modules
in app/code

Comment: you can refer below link.. this will helps you.

Comment: Plugin and Module is are same or different

Comment: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

Comment: plugin and module both are different things

Comment: Can i get Email for future contact

Answer (score 0):

Choose between **Create a new module** or **Override core modules** depends on your business requirement and your time and your cost.

As Magento provide  a strong platform for an e-commerce platform,so if your requirement is easy to manage from Magento exits modules, then **off course go ahead of  Core override using [PLugin](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html)** or [PREFERENCE](https://www.dckap.com/blog/magento-2-plugin-and-preference/),

For override a class and a method at Magento 2 what you want to use between plugin or preference then it your class but if you want to override **an method/class** then off course go to With Plugin.

[Magento2: what is the basic difference between plugin and preference?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/85277/magento2-what-is-the-basic-difference-between-plugin-and-preference)

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/build/di-xml-file.html

Comment: Thank you  but i know how to create module basic module 
how i can change the core functionality 
can i edit code in vendor folder

Comment: NO,Both case, you have to create a custom module where you have to define plugin or preference for change the core class or core method behavior.

Comment: what is preference

Comment: have  to check the link provide me  on `off course go ahead of Core override using PLugin or PREFERENCE,`   text?

Comment: ok thank you but have some confusion on changing core functionality

Comment: http://www.coolryan.com/magento/2016/01/22/preferences-in-magento-2/

Comment: I already explain  modify on core functionality is total depends on your business requirement and how you want to manage/implement  it  using Magento feature like plugin & preference

Answer (score 0):

This is a very wide topic. There are quite a few interaction methods between custom (your) code and other code, e.g. Magento core. You should really read the Magento Developer Documentation to familiarise yourself with basic concepts.

There are guides for both [front-end](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/bk-frontend-dev-guide.html) and [backend](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/bk-extension-dev-guide.html) developers.

First, you must understand the concept of a **module**. Module is a structural element of Magento 2. The whole system is built upon modules and your customisation starts with building a module. [Instructions on how to create a new module.](https://devdocs.magento.com/videos/fundamentals/create-a-new-module/)

There are many ways how your module can interact or override the Magento core (or any other module, for that matter).

- You can substitute a core class with your own class. This is called [dependency injection](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/depend-inj.html).
- You can excecute your own code before and/or after a function call. This is called [plugins](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html).
- At various points Magento fires events, and you hook your own code to be executed at an event. This is called [event-observer pattern](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/events-and-observers.html).