# Why use preference, when you can use plugins and when you can use observer in Magento2?

Tags: magento2

Magento2 has Three ways of extending Feature in native Magento classes and methods

> 1. Preference
> 2. Plugins
> 3. Observer

**Which one Use on in which Event ?**

Comment: Check for more information.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/85277/magento2-what-is-the-basic-difference-between-plugin-and-preference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Check This Links :-**

[Code customization techniques in Magento 2](https://kiwee.eu/code-customization-magento-2/)

[Overriding classes in Magento 2Overriding classes in Magento 2](https://inchoo.net/magento-2/overriding-classes-magento-2/)

[Magento 2 Development Fundamentals: Creating and Extending Classes](https://www.pushon.co.uk/blog/magento-2-development-fundamentals-creating-extending-classes/)

Answer (score 1):

A broad summary

Try and use plugins where possible. This will have least amount of impact and (hopefully) work well with other extensions. Plugins are super flexible. Best use case is when you want to swap out the value of a entity method for something more dynamic. Plugins take a bit of experimentation to get right.

Plugin for username login

https://github.com/DominicWatts/UsernameLogin/blob/master/Plugin/Magento/Customer/Model/AccountManagement.php

Use observer when a particular event would trigger an action in your extension. For example product save updates external search service with updated attribute values. Observations can be difficult to debug. Use lots of logging.

Last use preference. Complete rewrite of class or method within. Can add new methods. Only rewrite public methods. If your new method requires something not public this will need to be handled. This approach is probably the easiest to follow.

Preference rewrite of contact us post action

https://github.com/DominicWatts/ContactCc/blob/master/Rewrite/Magento/Contact/Controller/Index/Post.php

You can also override classes using composer. But this is outside the scope of your question.